# Security error when trying to add an Exchange account

Tags: email, exchange

I use Zarafa as my private Exchange server and that account works fine with my phone.  When I add a second Exchange account for my company it does install at first and connects to the MS Exchange server, but when synchronizing the connection is refused due to a security error.

How can I fix this? Does it have to do with signature or certificate problems? (I have tried enabling "Accept all certificates")

My phone: Samsung Galaxy S2, Android 2.3.3

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to enable or disable TLS or SSL for the account.